# ideas for a 301 redirect wildcards?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I'm having some trouble in finding an answer for a 301 redirect problem. The story goes like this:
I used to have a German language news site at www.punkto.ro. Every new article created with the site's CMS had the form: punkto.ro/articles/title-1234.html, where the 1234 is replaced by the article's number in the database. 
For several reasons I had to redesign and opted for wordpress, which I placed in the root. I created a subdomain archive.punkto.ro and replaced the url variable "punkto.ro" in a config.php file with "archive.punkto.ro". Then I moved the site files to the subdirectory "archive". It works fine. 
Of course, old article links in google now lead to a 404 response. To be sure, I also indicated the location of the archives on the 404, so people can go look there.
Now to the redirect: what I want to achieve is that when a user clicks a link in google punkto.ro/articles/title-1234.html, he/she should be redirected to archive.punkto.ro/articles/title-1234.html. 
The strange stuff is that I can't find the folder "articles" in my file manager (cpanel OR ftp)... Does anybbody have any idea as to how the .htacces should look like?

Examples:
Old link: `http://www.punkto.ro/articles/Staatschef_Basescu:_Rumaenien_einschliesslich_gesetzmaessig_fuer_Grexit_gewappnet-4169.html`

New link: `http://www.archive.punkto.ro/articles/Staatschef_Basescu:_Rumaenien_einschliesslich_gesetzmaessig_fuer_Grexit_gewappnet-4169.html`

Comment: +1 for explaining the problem in great detail.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you have to create the .htacccess-file in the "articles"-folder. Just create it in the main folder.
I hope this will work for you:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?punkto.ro$
RewriteRule ^articles/(.*)$ http://www.archive.punkto.ro/articles/$1 [L,NC,R=301]
```

The RewriteCond makes sure that www.archive.punkto.ro will not be redirected again, the RewriteCond redirects every URL containing "articles/" to the archiv.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It didn't work, probably due to some coding in the original CMS files and rules in the existing .htaccess file. But I managed to take care of the problem via some wordpress plugin that writes the 301 redirection. It's simply called "redirection", I don't understand exactly what file it modifies. Thanks again!!!